# Power Query M loop table / lookup via a self-join

Tags: loops, powerquery

First of all I'm new to power query, so I'm taking the first steps. But I need to try to deliver sometime at work so I can gain some breathing time to learn.

I have the following table (example):

```
Orig_Item       Alt_Item    
5.7             5.10
79.19           79.60
79.60           79.86
10.10
```

And I need to create a column that will loop the table and display the final `Alt_Item`. So the result would be the following:

```
Orig_Item       Alt_Item        Final_Item  
5.7             5.10            5.10    
79.19           79.60           79.86   
79.60           79.86           79.86   
10.10
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is far too complicated for a first Power Query experience.

If that's what you've got to do, then so be it, but you should be aware that you are starting with a quite difficult task.

Small detail: I would expect the last Final_Item to be 10.10. According to the example, the Final_Item will be null if Alt_Item is null. If that is not correct, well that would be a nice first step for you to adjust the code below accordingly.

You can create a new blank query, copy and paste this code in the Advanced Editor (replacing the default code) and adjust the Source to your table name.

```
let
    Source = Table.Buffer(Table1),
    AddedFinal_Item = 
      Table.AddColumn(
        Source, 
        "Final_Item", 
        each if [Alt_Item] = null
             then null
             else List.Last(
                    List.Generate(
                        () => [Final_Item = [Alt_Item], Continue = true],
                        each [Continue],
                        each [Final_Item = 
                                    Table.First(
                                        Table.SelectRows(
                                            Source, 
                                            (x) => x[Orig_Item] = [Final_Item]),
                                        [Alt_Item = "not found"]
                                                        )[Alt_Item], 
                              Continue = Final_Item <> "not found"],
                        each [Final_Item])))
in
    AddedFinal_Item
```

This code uses function **List.Generate** to perform the looping.
For performance reasons, the table should always be buffered in memory (Table.Buffer), before invoking List.Generate.

List.Generate is one of the most complex Power Query functions.

It requires 4 arguments, each of which is a function in itself.

In this case the first argument starts with () and the other 3 with each (it should be clear from the outline above: they are aligned).

**Argument 1** defines the initial values: a record with fields Final_Item and Continue.

**Argument 2** is the condition to continue: if an item is found.

**Argument 3** is the actual transformation in each iteration: the Source table is searched (with Table.SelectRows) for an Orig_Item equal to Alt_Item. This is wrapped in Table.First, which returns the first record (if any found) and accepts a default value if nothing found, in this case a record with field Alt_Item with value "not found", From this result the value of record field [Alt_Item] is returned, which is either the value of the first record, or "not found" from the default value.

If the value is "not found", then Continue becomes *false* and the iterations will stop.

**Argument 4** is the value that will be returned: Final_Item.

List.Generate returns a list of all values from each iteration. Only the last value is required, so List.Generate is wrapped in List.Last.

Final remark: actual looping is rarely required in Power Query and I think it should be avoided as much as possible. In this case, however, it is a feasible solution as you don't know in advance how many Alt_Items will be encountered.
An alternative for List.Generate is using a **resursive function**.
Also **List.Accumulate** is close to looping, but that has a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation, I will look into it over the weekend.

Any tips for a beginner?

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation, ended up by trying it last night. It was taking a while, though it would be because the table has around 2000 lines, so I left it thinking overnight. As I woke up today it was still thinking. Stopped it, tried again and it is still going. Any reason for taking this long? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: After looking into it, I realised that the problem was the list.last. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe I found the problem, there values that were duplicated. I removed them and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved simply with a self-join, the open question is how many layers of indirection you'll be expected to support.

Assuming just one level of indirection, no duplicates on Orig_Item, the solution is:

```
let
    Source = #"Input Table",
    SelfJoin1 = Table.NestedJoin( Source, {"Alt_Item"}, Source, {"Orig_Item"}, "_tmp_" ),
    Expand1   = ExpandTableColumn( SelfJoin1, "_tmp_", {"Alt_Item"}, {"_lkp_"} ),
    ChkJoin1  = Table.AddColumn( Expand1, "Final_Item", each (if [_lkp_] = null then [Alt_Item] else [_lkp_]), type number)
in
    ChkJoin1
```

This is doable with the regular UI, using Merge Queries, then Expand Column and adding a custom column.

If yo want to support more than one level of indirection, turn it into a function to be called X times. For data-driven levels of indirection, you wrap the calls in a list.generate that drop the intermediate tables in a structured column, though that's a much more advanced level of PQ.