# how to use List.Generate as a loop

Tags: powerquery

This might be simple but would appreciate any help to push me in the right direction.  I am trying to use the list.generate in power query to count number of tix based on the difference from 1-5.  It is a must that a loop is used such as the list.generate.

current tix-1

current tix-2

current tix-3

current tix-4

current tix-5

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Count", each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", (C) => 
(
    [Tix]=C[Tix]-(List.Generate(()=>1,each _ 5, each _ - 1))
    )
    )[Column1]))
```

Here is the sample data.  The idea is for me to able to put in the generated series of number as a loop.  this is the simplest representation because for other formula, I need the generated number as the x eg. (-1/2 x*x + 41/2 x).

```
+-------------+------------+
 TIX          |TIX count   |
5,000,243     | 0          |
6,991,904     | 0          |
6,991,905     | 1          |
6,991,906     | 2          |
6,991,907     | 3          |
6,991,908     | 4          |
7,000,234     | 0          |
+-------------+------------+
```

To simply put my targeted code should be something like this which i believe could be simplify by list.generate.

```
        = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Count", each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", (C) => 
(
    [Tix]=C[Tix]-1
   +[Tix]=C[Tix]-2
   +[Tix]=C[Tix]-3
   +[Tix]=C[Tix]-4
   +[Tix]=C[Tix]-5 )
    )
    )[Column1]))
```

Tried another code based on almost similar post : [Power Query M loop table / lookup via a self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839575/power-query-m-loop-table-lookup-via-a-self-join).
This also returns an error.  Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    #"Renamed Columns", 
    "Count", 
        List.Sum(
                List.Generate(
                    () => [Continue = 1],
                    each [Continue]<6,
                    each [Count = 
                                List.Count(
                                    Table.SelectRows(
                                        #"Renamed Columns", 
                                        (x) => x[Tix]-[Continue]= [Tix]))[Column1]],
                                                     each [Count])))
```

Comment: Do you have any sample inputs and outputs to show what you want? In general, `List.Generate` takes a fourth argument that is a function from the value generated by List.Generate and outputs whatever you wanted to use that value for.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT thanks for the comment.  I have updated it with sample.  Can you elaborate on the fourth argument.

Answer (score 0):

thru research, i found the solution:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", 
"Count", each List.Sum(
List.Generate(
() => [Count=List.Count(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2",
(C) => C[Tix] = [Tix]-Continue)
[Column1]),
Continue =1],
each [Continue]<=10,
each [Final_Item = [Final_Item], 
Continue =[Continue]+1],
each [Count])))
```